# .NET Core : I can not connect with a certificate X509Certificate2 created from base 64

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-core, x509certificate2

I am trying to create a certificate from base64 file using this code

```
 var certBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(string_base64_from_file);
 authCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certBytes);
```

After I use this certificate to connect to a web service

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = authCertificate;
```

But when I call this service, it returns this error

```
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'service_endpoint'
```

This same code works perfectly under framework.net 4.5, but not under .net core 2.1

can someone give me an idea?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Does the file you are reading includes private key? Or it is only public certificate. You need a certificate with associated private key.

Comment: Hello @Crypt32 Thank you for your answer, I think it was missing the private key.
I redid a test by creating a base64 chain with this code next ````
   var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String (authCertificate.Export (X509ContentType.SerializedCert, string.Empty)); ````

and it works

Comment: Serialized cert isn't the right type too. You need to export certificate to PFX type.

Comment: I just tested with X509ContentType.Pfx, it does not work
here is my code   

 // getting authCertificate and signatureCertificate from store windows
   authCertificate = new X509Certificate2(authCertificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, string.Empty), string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
   signatureCertificate = new X509Certificate2(signatureCertificate.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, string.Empty), string.Empty, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);

Comment: @Crypt32 any idea please ?